# Restrict TFS merge only to selected changesets

Tags: merge

The merge operation in TFS allows one of this two options to be selected:

-All changes up to a specific version

or

-Selected changesets

Is there any way to disable the first one?
We would like to avoid a potential mistake by restricting the merging scope operation exclusively to a given number of changesets (and not the whole team project).

Has anyone any suggestions as to achieve this?

Comment: There is no such switch or feature to disable that. I usually merge by all changes by default, since it's a lot more work to merge by changeset and chances of missing things is much higher, thus in itself a chance of potential mistake...

Comment: There is no chance for us to merge all changes together since there is no way to perform a full testing of all features. Once one feature is tested and approved by the users it should be merged into production branch (so we need to merge the changes by changeset number). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it's best to use feature branches. Before merging a feature to Main, do a reverse integration from main to your feature branch, have the feature tested and approved and then merge it to Main. Given the process you're following, you would need to merge and test features serially, but it might work.

That way you're always using Merge Latest and you'd be releasing everything only when tested.

I'd also seriously consider investing in automated tests, since then you'd be able to always test all features and you'd no longer have to work around these issues.

For more information on Feature branches, check out the [ALM Ranger Guidance on Branching and Merging](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/), especially the Feature plan.

The trick essentially is to create a branch per feature, directly from MAIN. Then regularly merge from MAIN to that feature branch (at least once just before merging back to main). That way you can create a build and test the feature with all the latest stuff in Main. When the test is approved, merge the feature branch back to main and release everything that is there.

The biggest downside to this is that in your case it wouldn't be easy to test and release two features together in one g, unless they're built on the same feature branch.

Whatever you decide to do, try to remove the impediments that cause you to need cherrypicking merges. They're very error prone and usually involve a lot of overhead that can be prevented using a better (plug-in) architecture, feature toggling, dependency injection and automated testing (both unit and integration). That way you can test more in one go and that way you can ship with partially completed features (turned off).